# javascriptの戻り値でn++としたときにはじめにゼロになる理由がわからない。

Tags: javascript

javascriptの勉強をしており、書籍を見ていると、下のようなパターンのコードがでてきます。
関数の中に関数があるパターンです。

```
function counter(){
    var n = 0;
    return{
        count: function(){return n++;},
        reset: function(){n = 0;}
    };
}
var c = counter(), d = counter();
console.log(c.count());//0
console.log(c.count());//1
```

こちらのコードのcountメソッドを呼び出すと最初になぜか0になります。
n++としているので最初に呼び出しときに1になるのでは？と思ってしまいます。
なぜ0になるのか教えていただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

インクリメント演算子で`n++`と書いたときに加算前の値が返されるのは、JavaScriptの仕様です。
加算した後の値を参照したい場合、`++n`と書く必要があります。

---

算術演算子 - JavaScript | MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88_()

> - オペランドの後に演算子を置く（例：x++）後置記法で使った場合、加算する前の値を返します。

```js
var n = 0;
console.log(n++);
console.log(n);
```

> - オペランドの前に演算子を置く（例：++x）前置記法で使った場合、加算した後の値を返します。

```js
var n = 0;
console.log(++n);
console.log(n);
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。勉強になりました。